# Android Cast v3: can't find any device

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I'm trying to integrate the android cast v3 into my app and can't make it work.

I did exactly what written in this google document:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate
(until the header: "Configure device discovery")

And the dialog that opened when I click on the MediaRouteButton can't find any device while the "youtube" app success to find my android-tv device.

what did I missed?

```
// the code of the CastOptionsProvider:
class CastOptionsProvider implements OptionsProvider {

    @Override
    public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context appContext) {
        return new CastOptions.Builder().setReceiverApplicationId(
                CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID).build();
    }

    @Override
    public List<SessionProvider> getAdditionalSessionProviders(Context context) {
        return null;
    }
}

// the code in the custom view:
mMediaRouteButton = (MediaRouteButton)findViewById(R.id.media_route_button);
    CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(getContext(), mMediaRouteButton);
mCastContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(getContext());
```

and in the manifest (inside the application tag):

```
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
     android:value="com.bla-company-bla.core.cast.CastOptionsProvider"/>
```

Comment: Are you using a custom receiver, the Default receiver or a styled receiver?

Comment: Using the default.

Comment: You then need show some code around setting up your CastSession, your OptionProvider and such.

Comment: Do I have to set-up CastSession to find devices?
according to the google document I mentioned in the question, you need to to declare only OptionProvider.

Comment: For discovery, OptionProvider and CastContext initialization should be enough so include your code around those areas.

Comment: done (the code included in the question text)

Comment: Putting aside YT, do other apps find your Android-TV device, such as Google Play Music? Is hat the only cast device you have on your network?